# Having trouble grasping simple boolean loop if/else program in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

I need a little help figuring out a couple of parts from a C++ assignment. I am asked to write a program as follows:

Write a program that accepts input from the keyboard (with the input
terminated by pressing the Enter key) and counts the number of letters (A-Z and a-z), numerical digits (0-9), and other characters. Input the string using cin and use the following looping structure to examine each character in the string with an "if" statement and multiple "else if" statements.

```
char s[50];
int i;

. . .

i = 0;
while (s[i] != 0) { // a string is terminated with a null (0) value

. . .

i++;
}
```

Your program should make use of the relational operators (e.g., == < > <= >= !=) to determine whether a particular character is a letter, number, or other character. You may only #include  and
may not use any other include files.

The program should have an output similar to the following:

Enter a continuous string of characters with no blank spaces (example: `aBc1234!@#$%`)

enter your string: `aBc1234!@#$%`

```
your string has 12 total characters
3 letters
4 numerical characters
5 other characters
```

Here is an example program that counts lower case letters:

```
// PROG07.CPP example

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
char s[50];
int i;
int lowercase = 0;

//get string from the user
cout << "Enter a continuous string of characters with no blanspaces\n"
cout << "(example: aBc1234!@#$%)" << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter your string: ";
cin >> s;
cout << endl;

// loop through the string, lower case letters
// note, strings (character arrays) have an invisible
// zero value at their end
i = 0;
while (s[i] != 0) // while the character does not have ASCII code zero
{
if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z'))
lowercase++;
i++;
}

cout << "Your string has " << lowercase << " lower case letters" << endl;

// including the next line for Dev-C++:
system("pause"); // not needed for CodeBlocks

return 0;
}
```

So far, I have come up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char s[50];
int i;
int lowercase, uppercase, numChars, otherChars = 0;

cout << "Enter a continuous string of characters" << endl;
cout << "(example: aBc1234!@#$%)" << endl;
cout << "Enter your string: ";
cin >> s;
cout << endl;

while (s[i] != 0) // while the character does not have ASCII code zero
{
if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z'))
    lowercase++;
    i++;
}
while (s[i] != 0)
{
if ((s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
    uppercase++;
    i++;
}
cout << lowercase + uppercase << " letters" << endl;
i = 0;
while (s[i] != 0)
{
if ((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
    numChars++;
    i++;
}

cout << numChars << " numerical characters" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put all the tests in the one loop, no need to loop repeatedly. And the problem you're having with this approach is that you're not resetting `i` after the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset i to 0 before every loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char s[50];
int i;
int lowercase, uppercase, numChars, otherChars = 0;

cout << "Enter a continuous string of characters" << endl;
cout << "(example: aBc1234!@#$%)" << endl;
cout << "Enter your string: ";
cin >> s;
cout << endl;

i = 0; //missing
while (s[i] != 0) // while the character does not have ASCII code zero
{
if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z'))
    lowercase++;
    i++;
}
i = 0; // missing
while (s[i] != 0)
{
if ((s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
    uppercase++;
    i++;
}
cout << lowercase + uppercase << " letters" << endl;
i = 0;
while (s[i] != 0)
{
if ((s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
    numChars++;
    i++;
}

cout << numChars << " numerical characters" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks good so far, just a few things

First off, you only need the one `while` loop:

```
while (s[i] != 0)
{
    //All your if checks can go in here
}
```

Then, according to the output you need, you will need 4 variables:

```
int total, lettters, numbers, otherCharacters;
```

At the start of your loop, add to total:

```
while (s[i] != 0)
{
    total++;
}
```

Then you will need 3 if checks inside your while loop, one for letters, one for numbers, and one for other characters:

```
if ((s[i] > 'a' && s[i] < 'z') || (s[i] > 'A' && s[i] < 'Z')) { ... }
else if (s[i] > '0' && s[i] < '9') { ... }
else { ... }
```

Then just output all your variables according to the output you mentioned:

```
cout << "your string has " << total << " total characters, " << letters << " letters, " << numbers << " numerical characters, and " << otherCharacters << " characters.";
```